# How do I check for errors in one line for-loop?

Tags: python

I am trying the process the following list in a one line for-loop. The program produces a 'No such file or directory' error if the system is missing a drive. How do I handle this error?

```
(1, 18911232, 'af1a83d6b18bf3e065be82cf44246037', 'D')
(2, 18911744, 'd5cedca078545cbcb0b2a9b514f9b92d', 'D')
(3, 18912256, '457ee2f5dc6f95b09599fc3f479878b6', 'D')
(4, 27076608, '8fb1ee8d6d8df00e53055e0eb48ef2e5', 'E')
(5, 27077120, 'a9ea5ccfebe4d6b3ecdd429518fff688', 'E')
(6, 27077632, 'ff722e8bb3c731ece625f882a090f100', 'E')
(7, 19604324352, 'd1fd613c04c983d73d79027f2a3425f9', 'C')
(8, 19604324864, '6f51f480b2ad733f20a54c8d3f5dd38c', 'C')
(9, 19604325376, '066fdaddf301b83402934e5783a3eec3', 'C')
```

```
drive_map = {item[3]: open(r"\\." + '\\'+ item[3] + ':', 'rb') for item in myList}
        for item in myList:
            disk = drive_map[item[3]]
```

Comment: The for loops is kind of irrelevant to the problem. This is just a matter of handling errors from `open`.

Comment: your indentation is off anyhow, but the error is not in the for loop, but in the dict comp (where you call `open()`.  What should happen at failure anyhow?

Comment: So your question actually is: how do I handle an (I/O) error inside a list comprehension? (A list comprehension is the normal name for what you call a one-line-for-loop.)

Comment: Note that in this particular case I wouldn't use a dict comp and then immediately iterate it: I'd do it all in an explicit loop, which greatly clarifies the error handling.

Comment: I'm just curious: what does ```\\.\C:``` means on Windows machines? What happens when you `open()` it? I'm asking because I'm under the impression that [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) would be a better alternative to solve your problem.

Comment: That returns a handle to a file/disk.

Comment: Yep. That's clear for me. But why test it that way? Is it just to check if that drive is available? ```\\.\<drive_letter>:``` has any special meaning on Windows? `pathlib.Path().exists()` seems like a better option IMHO. Another thing is why repeat the test for a drive that was already tested?

Comment: `os.path.exists(r"\\." + '\\'+ item[3] + ':')` checks that the path exists, and `open(r"\\." + '\\'+ item[3] + ':', 'rb')` opens the drive.                                                `\\.\<drive_letter>:` is one way to open drives/disks

Answer (score 0):

My main answer is: don't put this inside a list comprehension. Use a normal loop, and handle it there with try-except:

```
for item in myList:
    try:
        open(...)
    except IOError:
        # do something practical,
        # or
        pass
```

(`IOError` handles other I/O errors than, for example, `FileNotFoundError`s as well.)

Or better, with a context manager:

```
for item in myList:
    try:
        with open(...) as fp:
            # do something with the opened filepointer `fp`
    except IOError as exc:
        # If some I/O error occurred, we inform the user on the command line,
        # but the file will be safely closed if it was open
        print(exc)
```

---

If you feel like you absolutely must, write a wrapper function that returns the open file, or None otherwise:

```
def my_open(filename):
    try:
        fp = open(filename)
    except IOError:
        fp = None
    return None
```

This is horrible, in the sense that you need to explicitly take care to close the file aftwards: you can't use a context manager like

```
with open(filename) as fp:
    # do something with the open file
```

which closes the file aterwards, no matter whether there is an error or not.

But, with the above function, you could now do:

```
drive_map = {item[3]: fp for item in myList 
             if (fp := my_open(r"\\." + '\\'+ item[3] + ':', 'rb')) is not None}
```

which uses assignment expressions introduced in Python 3.8

Again, this is very hacky, so you probably want to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this may it help you.

```
import os
drive_map = [open(r"\\." + '\\'+ item[3] + ':', 'rb') for item in myList if os.path.exists(r"\\." + '\\'+ item[3] + ':')]
```

The desire file will open only when the if condition return true.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, if you *did* need to put some error handling inside a comprehension, you have two options:

#### Detect the condition yourself

```py
things = [0, 1, "2 ", "3 ", "4 "]
print([x.strip() for x in things if isinstance(str, x) else x])
```

This is liable to lead to ugly code for anything other than trivial conditions.

#### Write a robust handler and apply that

In this case we basically treat the comprehension as `map()`.

```py
def f(x):
    try:
        return x.strip()
    except AttributeError:
        return x

print([f(x) for x in things])
```

(N.B. This is a toy example, and a simple cast to `int` would make a lot more sense here).

For an IO error I would use the second method (the first is subject to race conditions if it tests for a file which then appears/disappears).  However I would not use either here, and would use an explicit loop, since:

- your code is rather hard to read at the moment
- you immediately iterate the dict anyway
- this method involves a function call every time, and will thus be less performant, for no good reason.